# Plot a gaussian distribution in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, assembly

are there any libraries to plot a gaussian distribution, and measure position along that curve? like https://github.com/errcw/gaussian in javascript

Comment: Certainly you can make heavy calculations in solidity, but it will be expensive and consume lots of resources. Solidity and blockchain are not designed with heavy computation in mind. Also you are limited by the block gas limit that put a cap on how much calculation can be done in a single transaction. Usually heavy computation is done off-blockchain and only minimal is done with solidity, perhaps to store proof of the work done.

Comment: gaussian distributions are not that much calculations, just plot-points, total, mean, difference, variance, more or less. if there was a library I would use that, but I can write it myself also probably

Comment: Gaussian distributions are not plot points, the bell shape in a Gaussian distribution comes for the calculation of an exponential function, the calculation over the domain of the independent variable is easily performed in a pc, but in Etehreum every operation cost ether!

Comment: wrote an answer a few minutes prior to your comment, feel free to see if it does not work
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49516/plot-a-gaussian-distribution-in-solidity/49535#49535

Comment: So you solved your problem, good!. If you did so, accept your own answer. Good luck.

Comment: seems to me like it would work, a couple of plot points, then the mean, difference, variance, standard deviation, sigma, and quite gas friendly

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this here is enough for a gaussian distribution,

```
contract gaussianDistribution {

struct BellCurve {
    uint population;
    uint total;
    uint mean;
    uint standardDeviation;
    mapping(address => uint) plot;
    mapping(address => uint) differences;
    uint differences_squared_sum;
    uint variance;
    mapping(address => uint) sigma;
}

BellCurve bellcurve;

function calculateMean() {
  require(bellcurve.mean == 0);
  bellcurve.mean = bellcurve.total / bellcurve.population;
}

function calculateDifference(address _node) {
  require(bellcurve.variance == 0);
  uint mean = bellcurve.mean;
  require(mean != 0); // Has the mean been calculated first?
  uint plot = bellcurve.plot[_node];
  require(plot != 0); // Is the person in the record?
  require(bellcurve.differences[_node] == 0); // Has this person been processed already?
  uint difference = mean - plot;
  bellcurve.differences[_node] = difference;
  bellcurve.differences_squared_sum += difference^2;
}

function calculateVariance() {
  uint variance = bellcurve.differences_squared_sum / bellcurve.population;
  bellcurve.variance = variance;
}

  function calculateStandardDeviation() {
    uint variance = bellcurve.variance;
    require(variance != 0);
    bellcurve.standardDeviation = sqrt(bellcurve.variance);
}

function sqrt(uint x) returns (uint y) {
    uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
    y = x;
    while (z < y) {
        y = z;
        z = (x / z + z) / 2;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: An issue you might have is that since you are using `uint` for the difference it will overflow if the result is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is used to write code for the Ethereum Virtual Machine, is not used to write pc programs or control GUI. You can find an introduction to Block-chain, Etehreum and the EVM [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#blockchain-basics)

Hope this help

Comment: yes I know. are there libraries for normal distribution graphs?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: You can't plot anything using solidity. As it was said, it just execute basic code with (relatively) basic logic.

Comment: assembly, turing complete, etc

Comment: I guess you could do it. But it would be like writing a device driver in typescript, or 3D graphics code in PL/SQL. It's the wrong use for the tool. No one is working on libraries to misuse Solidity.

Comment: is it not just something like this in my answer to this question? rather than being complex 3d graphics code, you just take the data points, add them together, divide to find the average, subtract each point from the average, square, the difference^2, and add all those together to get variance, and then square root of variance for standard deviation
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49516/plot-a-gaussian-distribution-in-solidity?noredirect=1#comment58714_49516

since each person invokes their own "part" of calculating that, quite gas friendly?

Comment: I do not think we all are understanding the same when you use the word plot. People (me included) are relating this to make a graph of the distribution. You talk about the plot as data points. All this aside, I thought you have solved the problem, no? if not, please update the question to clarify what do you need.

Comment: is it not plotted with this? including being gas friendly, and all that, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49516/plot-a-gaussian-distribution-in-solidity/49535#49535

can grab the data, and have a graph on front end if you want